# How to include Jquery lib for ajax in icn3d?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys i have big problem i don't know how to add jquery lib 3.5.0 in icn3d "setDialog.js" i already try to do this by js code or html code when i do this i have so many errors i try to add own button in icn3d menu i almost did it, but when i click run in own added code i have problems with ajax here is my code:

```
/////////
        html += me.htmlCls.divStr + "dl_mutation_2' class='" + dialogClass + "'>";
        html += this.addNotebookTitle('dl_mutation_2', 'Electron transfer pathways calculations');
        html += "<div style='width:500px'>";
        html += '<h2>Electron transfer pathways calculations_1</h2>';
        html += `
          <style>
        
        .submit {
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(45deg,#000 25%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 50%,#000 75%);
        mask-image: linear-gradient(45deg,#000 25%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 50%,#000 75%);
        -webkit-mask-size: 800%;
        mask-size: 800%;
        
        }
        
        </style>
        <label for="name"><b>Enter name of project:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" style="font-size: 13px; border-radius: 8px;" class="custom-input">
        <span id="name-error"></span>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="file"><b>Select PDB file:</b></label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <span id="file-error"></span>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="atom1"><b>Enter donor:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="atom1" id="atom1" placeholder="Donor" style="font-size: 13px; border-radius: 8px;" class="custom-input">
        <span id="atom1-error"></span>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="atom2"><b>Enter acceptor:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="atom2" id="atom2" placeholder="Acceptor" style="font-size: 13px; border-radius: 8px;" class="custom-input">
        <span id="atom2-error"></span>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Run!" onclick="return validateForm();" style="width: 100px;height: 40px;background-color: green;color: white;padding: 8px 16px;border: none;border-radius: 10px;cursor: pointer;">
        </div>
        
        <div id="output"></div>
        
        <script>
        function validateForm() {
        
          var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
          var fileInput = document.getElementById("file");
          var atom1Input = document.getElementById("atom1");
          var atom2Input = document.getElementById("atom2");
          var isValid = true;
        
          if (nameInput.value.trim() === "") {
            document.getElementById("name-error").textContent = "Please fill in the name of project field.";
            document.getElementById("name-error").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("name").classList.add("required-field");
            isValid = false;
          } else {
            document.getElementById("name-error").textContent = "";
            document.getElementById("name").classList.remove("required-field");
          }
        
          if (fileInput.value.trim() === "") {
            document.getElementById("file-error").textContent = "Please select a PDB file.";
            document.getElementById("file-error").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("file").classList.add("required-field");
            isValid = false;
          } else {
            document.getElementById("file-error").textContent = "";
            document.getElementById("file").classList.remove("required-field");
          }
        
          if (atom1Input.value.trim() === "") {
            document.getElementById("atom1-error").textContent = "Please fill in the donor field.";
            document.getElementById("atom1-error").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("atom1").classList.add("required-field");
            isValid = false;
          } else {
            document.getElementById("atom1-error").textContent = "";
            document.getElementById("atom1").classList.remove("required-field");
          }
        
          if (atom2Input.value.trim() === "") {
            document.getElementById("atom2-error").textContent = "Please fill in the acceptor field.";
            document.getElementById("atom2-error").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("atom2").classList.add("required-field");
            isValid = false;
          } else {
            document.getElementById("atom2-error").textContent = "";
            document.getElementById("atom2").classList.remove("required-field");
          }
        
          if (!isValid) {
            alert("Please fill in all the required fields.");
            return false;
          }   
        
              var name = $("#name").val(); // Get the command from the input field
              var file = $("#file")[0].files[0]; // Get the command from the input field
              var atom_1 = $("#atom1").val(); // Get the command from the input field
              var atom_2 = $("#atom2").val(); // Get the command from the input field
        
              var formData = new FormData();
              formData.append("name", name);
              formData.append("file", file);
              formData.append("atom1", atom_1);
              formData.append("atom2", atom_2);
        
              // Send an AJAX request to the PHP script
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "input_pdb_file.php",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(output) {
                  $("#output").html(output); // Display the output in the output div
                },
                error: function() {
                  alert("Error occurred during AJAX submission.");
                }
              });
        
          //return isValid;
          return false;
        
        }</script>`;
 
        
        html += "<br/><br/></div></div>";
        //////////
```

I try to include jquery lib for ajax in icn3d file help pls.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for Ajax? Just use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

Normally there are two way to include jquery through js or through html:

Inside js file:

```
// setDialog.js
// ... Other imports ...

// Include jQuery library
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Inside Html(but you need to make sure jquery in before setDialog.js):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/setDialog.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you included jQuery library, you can call iCn3D function to make async ajax call such as "data = await me.getAjaxPromise(url, 'json', false);". The function "getAjaxPromise" is defined at https://github.com/ncbi/icn3d/blob/master/src/icn3dui.js

Answer (score -1):

My problem was in dollar $ now I use jquery.noConflict, I thought error was in lib but now i find answer.